# My database table is not ordered 

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

Sometimes when I insert a new row to a table in my database, it comes before the last row.

I will explain. If I have the following table:

```
ID Name
1 James
2 Terry
3. Miriam
4. Arthur
```

and I want to insert a new row with "Danny", sometimes this happens:

```
ID Name
1 James
2 Terry
3. Miriam
5. Danny
4. Arthur
```

My code works in 99 percent of the cases, but sometimes it just happens.
I do not know what to do? Is this normal?

I work with ASP.NET, VB.NET, .NET 3.5 and MySQL database with autoIncrement on the ID column.
I've seen it also happen in Access and SQL Server.

This is my code:

```
  ' insert to user_table
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mysql_ConnString").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connString)
    Dim sqlCommand As String

    sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO user_table (Nickname,Email,Pass,SubscriptionMode,SignupDate,LastVisitDate,VisitCounter) VALUES (@Nickname,@Email,@Pass,@SubscriptionMode,@SignupDate,@LastVisitDate,@VisitCounter)"

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nickname", txtNickname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", password)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubscriptionMode", 1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignupDate", Date.Now)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastVisitDate", Date.Now)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitCounter", 0)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        GlobalFunction.sendToLog(ex, "problem in create profile page - sub: insertUser_table")
        GlobalFunction.jsMessage(Me, "problem in create profile page - sub: insertUser_table")
        Return False
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: This looks like VB.NET (not C#). Please correct/re-tag as appropriate. Also include the error message(s) received.

Answer (score 7):

In general, when you do

```
select * from Users
```

you cannot rely on the order of records. if you need your records in some particular order, you'll have to explicitly specify an `order by` clause

```
select * from Users order by ID
```

Answer (score 2):

MySql is a Relational Database Management System which means that it is based on the relational model. The physical order of the rows of a table (which represents a relation) is of no importance. You must think of tables as Unorder Sets. If you want to present your data in a specific order you must use the order by clause.

I think that if you use InnoDB you can use a clustered index to specify the order of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

To correct your question: **My database table is not ordered**

Your database table **is** ordered, but your select statement is **not** ordered.
And because it is not that's why you're not getting an ordered result.
The result that you are getting is in **[undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_value)** order!

If you want an ordered result you **must** always specify and `order by` clause in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Make ID your primary key and make it indexed. No matter what your newly entered row will be the last one. For selecting use the suggestions above about order by.

Answer (score 0):

As Bala R said, you can't have SQL determine how you want to organize your data, so you want to do something like this:

`SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id ASC`

ex: (1,2,3,4,5)

Or this:

`SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id DESC`

ex: (5,4,3,2,1)